# Alamofire fails to build with cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, alamofire

I'm using:

```
OSX 10.11.3
Xcode 7.21
cocoapods 0.39.0
```

Here is my podfile

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
```

When I try to build my project, Alamofire has 23 errors. Random example: `expected ':' after case`

I've tried restarting xcode, cleaning, building, building just alamofire, `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`, but all with the same result.

This is my first time using cocoapods so I could be doing something completely wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently Alamofire is updated to support Xcode 7.3 and Swift 2.2 so you have to use Alamofire version 3.2.1 to use in Xcode 7.2.1.

So you have to write podfile to lock the version to 3.2.1.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
pod 'Alamofire', '3.2.1'
```

Comment: Thanks! perfect! `pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.2.1'` also seemed to work

Comment: Good to hear that! Would you select my answer?

Comment: yes, I will!, it won't let me until 5 minutes have gone by

Comment: I just downgraded Alamofire from 3.3.1 to 3.2.1 because of xcode 7.2.1 but still getting "No such module" when I try to import or use Alamofire's api in my code. Please help!!

Comment: Did you build your project??

Comment: what is the Alamofire version required for Xcode 7.3.1?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. This solved my problem. Currently my pod' s file has theses configurations below:

## Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project

platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

```
target 'MyProject' do
  # Pods for API Rest
  pod 'Alamofire', '3.2.1'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
end
```